# Ошибка при reshape и её отсутствие в аналогичном примере

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

1. Вот код, который выдаёт ошибку:

   ```
   train['Vectors'].shape
   (42900,)

   x_train = np.array(train['Vectors'].tolist()).reshape((len(train), 300 * 100))
   ```

   Ошибка:

   ```
   ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 42900 into shape (42900,30000)
   ```
2. Вот аналогичный код, который такой ошибки не выдаёт:

   ```
    train['Embeddings'].shape
    (11199,)

    x_train = np.array(train['Embeddings'].tolist()).reshape(len(train), 300 * 100)
   ```

Почему так происходит и что не так в первом случае?

Comment: Без исходных данных описываемое поведение не воспроизводится. Согласно [документации](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape), для `numpy.ndarray.reshape` записи `a.reshape(10, 11)` и `a.reshape((10, 11))` эквивалентны.

Comment: @АлексейР можете мне помочь? Суть в том, что я хочу обучить модель машинного обучения по определению тональности текста (отрицательный он или негативный). Я текст перевëл в векторные представления с помощью библиотеки navec. У меня получается так, что один текст - вектор, в котором каждое слово - это ещё один вектор. Как скормить это модели keras правильно?